# Is soda can fishing actually effective?

Tags: fishing, fishing-tackle

While out fishing on a popular gulf coast pier, I've seen some people pull in fish left and right using only a crumpled soda can as a lure tied to a hook and line. Meanwhile, I was using normal bait and tackle and left empty-handed.

Is this soda can technique actually effective or is it just luck (combined with good fishing technique)?

Comment: Do you mean that they use the soda can to store the line?

Comment: @Kenji no it was the lure

Comment: Wow. That is a new technique to me. Interesting.

Comment: As with most fishing, I'm sure this depends entirely on the type of fish being targeted.

Answer (score 5):

Sure you can use anything as a bait really. Think of a crushed up can as a funky spinner (it's going to spin no matter what you do to it). It's shiny, flashy and moves erratically like an injured fish.

I have also seen lures made by folding bottle caps around a hook shank.